# Usage of both apostrophe and “of” together

Tags: prepositions, apostrophe, grammatical-case, double-possessive

I was reading Agatha Christie’s *The Murder of Roger Ackroyd* and noticed following sentence:

> About those boots of Ralph Paton’s.

It is really in old (old as in early or mid twentieth century) English that they use apostrophe and *of* together? Would it not be proper to say:

> About those boots of Ralph Paton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have to use the so-called “double genitive” here:

> About those boots of Ralph **Paton’s**.

It has to be a noun or pronoun in the possessive case, not in the subject case. That’s why it is

> a friend of **mine**

Not

> a friend of ***me**

See other questions with the [double-genitive](/questions/tagged/double-genitive) tag for more examples and explanation.